# AS3 - Calling external Javascript

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, geolocation

I'm trying to pass the geolocation over Javascript to Flash. The .SWF is embedded in a HTML site and set to *AllowScriptAccess="always"*. 
For some reason the getGEO() function is not receiving the call.

JS:

```
<script>
        function getGEO()
        {
         alert("getGEO");
            if (navigator.geolocation)
            {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
                {
                    lat = position.coords.latitude
                    long = position.coords.longitude;
                    passGEOToSWF(lat, long);
                });
            } else {

            }
        }
```

AS3:

```
if (ExternalInterface.available) 
{  
    try 
    {
        ExternalInterface.call("getGEO");
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("passGEOToSWF", onPassGEOToSWF);
    } 
    catch (error:SecurityError) 
    {
    } 
    catch (error:Error) 
    {
    } 
}

function onPassGEOToSWF(lat:*,long:*):void
{
    trace(lat,long);
}
```

What do I miss here?

Comment: I suppose you use .js on a mobile device. Why not to use the flash native extensions to read the location ?

Answer (score 3):

You've got:

```
ExternalInterface.call("getGEO");
ExternalInterface.addCallback("passGEOToSWF", onPassGEOToSWF);
```

You may want to try:

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("passGEOToSWF", onPassGEOToSWF);
ExternalInterface.call("getGEO");
```

The external JS call may be completing before the AS3 registers the callback.

---

In order to get a reference to the flash movie, which you need in order to call the AS3 callback, you need a function like the following ([source](http://painteddigital.com/2008/calling-flash-as3-functions-from-javascript/))

```
function getFlashMovieObject(movieName){
    if (window.document[movieName]){
        return window.document[movieName];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1){
        if (document.embeds &amp;&amp; document.embeds[movieName])
            return document.embeds[movieName];
    }
    else{
        return document.getElementById(movieName);
    }
}
```

Once you have that reference, you can call the AS3 callback. Here's an example:

```
function SendDataToFlashMovie(lat, long){
    var flashMovie=getFlashMovieObject("main_flash");
    flashMovie.passGeoToSWF(lat, long);
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just looked closer at your JS. You need a reference to the flash movie before you can try to call a callback. If you look http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e92.html, it shows one example of how to access the swf from the javascript. If it doesn't work, there are many answers on SO about it.

Comment: Here's another link showing how to get a reference to the swf: http://painteddigital.com/2008/calling-flash-as3-functions-from-javascript/

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by _you need a reference to the flash movie_ - Can you please explain it a little further?

Comment: @Tom, take a look, I expanded my answer.

Comment: I can't get it work, sorry. Not even the `alert("getGEO")` comes up. Not sure what I'm missing here. Is there any tutorial with sources available too look at?

Comment: @Tom I thought you were failing to get back from JS -> AS3, not having issues with AS3 -> JS. Let me take another look.

Comment: @Tom how is your JS script integrated?

Comment: I'm not sure where it's failing. Can be AS3, JS or the HTML embedding part. `how is your JS script integrated?`It's in the HTML site.

Comment: Okay. Without more of your html wrapper, it's going to be difficult to help.

Comment: @Tom I just looked at your HTML wrapper, first thing I noticed: `alter("getGEO");` is *not* `alert("getGEO");`. Also, you need to have a reference to the **movie** not a div containing the movie.